# Pass a variable from a node.js page to an Angular2 app

Tags: node.js, angular

I am hosting an Angular2 app using Windows IIS7. I uploaded the Angular2 DIST folder contents and the app launches without issue in the browser. However, in the Angular2 app, right off the bat I need to know the logged-in Username. So I am using node.js to accomplish this. I have installed node.js on the server and am using iisnode. My index.js page contains the following code.

====================================

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
var index = fs.readFileSync('index.html');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  var username = req.headers['x-iisnode-logon_user'];    

  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});

  res.end(index);

  //res.end('username: ' + username);

}).listen(process.env.PORT);
```

=========================================

If I call my website using \index.js, this works great and I can view the username from the req.header logon_user data (when that I toggle the comment on the two res.end lines). 
It also works as expected when I am using res.end(index). I call the website using index.js and it immediately begins to launch my Angular2 app (of which index.html is the entry point). However, I cannot figure out how to get the username that was discovered by the .js page into my Angular2 app so I can use it. It can't be appended to the URL, for example, due to security concerns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Install Express in your node.js app
2. Create a REST API `api/user/` that will return the current user
3. Change your angular code to make an http request to the API and return the username.

Comment: thank you for that reply and the help. Express was indeed the way to go. It was quite a struggle getting Express, IIS, Node.js, and Angular2 to all play together well but it is now working. After getting the paths all finally set correctly so that IIS know when to serve up the .js pages and when to serve up the static pages, incorporating the http request to the REST Api worked great. thanks again.

Comment: Glad to hear. Please accept my answer if it helped.